# How to create variables according to text

Tags: python

Hi sir I want to know how I can create unlimited variables from text for example if I don't know what will be my text length.
I want to create variables from text here is code

```
txt = "Half Life is released in 1998 by Valve Corporation, revolutionized the first-person shooter (FPS) genre, setting new standards for storytelling, immersive gameplay, and technical innovation. Developed by a small team led by Gabe Newell, Half-Life quickly became a landmark title that left an indelible mark on the gaming industry."

x = txt.split(". ")

print(x)
```

I want different variables according to text size because i don't know what will be my text length

Comment: `x` will be a list of the sentences in your paragraph.  `x[0]` will have the first sentence, `x[1]` will have the second, and `for sentence in x:` lets you go through each one by one.

Comment: I already told I don't know the length of text it will be different every time

Comment: You probably want to read: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: It doesn't matter in the slightest.  The array that `split` returns will contain one element per sentence in the text, whether there are 2 sentences or 100.    Because you don't know the length, you NEED to work with the list and not try to create variables.

Comment: @TimRoberts how to use 100 variables from list if we get 100 sometime because the text i am getting i don't know how many variables will be in the list please help thanks

Comment: @MrPaulReviews After splitting the text you can get the size of the list with `len(x)`, and you can loop over all of the elements of the list with `for sentence in x:`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about.  If there are 100 sentences, then you will have `x[0]` through `x[99]`.  If you need to know how many there were, do `len(x)`, but in a case like that, you aren't going to be looking at the 57th entry.  You'll be doing the same processing on ALL the entries.  That's why a list is so great.